# When is apt prompting for user confirmation and if it does so, when does it default to "yes"

Tags: apt

**TL/DR: I think the accepted answer is a complete one to my expectation. Other answers that add useful info to the topic are still welcome.**

I have used both `rpm`(`dnf`) and `apt` package management systems. In `rpm` systems I notice when I update or install new packages it almost always prompts the user for confirmation and the default is "no" most of the time. In the `apt` system I notice that sometimes it does not prompt for the user confirmation and sometimes prompts the user with a default "yes".

So my question is, **when does `apt-get` or things alike prompt the user for confirmation, and if it does so, when does it defaults to yes?**

I think I should be able to find the answer if I dig through the source of `apt` but I have failed to do it, probably because I haven't used the right tool or the right method for processing the source code.

Note that I am **not asking for `apt-get -y`, `apt-get --assume-no` or things alike**. I know these options and I am not asking for someone to tell me that they exist. I am asking the behavior **when no additional command line flags are provided**. It may depend on command line options when compiling, but answering the behavior for the `apt` shipped in the default `debian` and `ubuntu` repos should be enough.

**Edit**:
I know there is [Apt-get install does not ask for confirmation](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/apt-get-install-does-not-ask-for-confirmation-859586/) on LinuxQuestions.org, but I have always thought that there are cases where the prompt of `apt-get` defaults to no (i.e. `[y/N]`), and I want evidence from the source.

From the accepted answer, it is clear that

> If the prompt is in the form
>
> ```
> Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
> ```
>
> It always defaults to yes.

From the comment in the accepted answer I finally found evidence from the source code that I have been looking for: https://github.com/Debian/apt/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=YnPrompt

So I think I have found a complete answer to my question.

**Edit 2**:
I realized not long after I accepted the answer, that I actually saw the `[y/N]` on `yum`-based systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apt-get upgrade` will always prompt.

`apt-get install` will only install automatically if there are no conflicts, held packages and all of the new packages to be installed were explicitly specified. That is if it brings in dependencies automatically it will prompt.

Comment: So if `apt-get install` prompts, when does it default to yes (i.e. `[Y/n]`) and when does it default to no (i.e. `[y/N]`)?

Comment: It doesn't. Either it prompts or it doesn't prompt. If you're talking about where --assume-yes will fail thats a different question isn't it?

Comment: I mean, "Do you want to continue? [Y/n]" vs. "Do you want to continue?[y/N]" I have seen both cases if I remember correctly.

Comment: That particular prompt will always be "Y/n" so if you press enter it assumes yes.

Comment: Thank you. Then maybe I have some confusion here, with the `rpm` system. I will mark the answer accepted.

Comment: I confirm that I have seen the `[y/N]` in `do-release-upgrade` which is a different story.

Comment: There are prompts in apt-get that default to no but they are for entirely different reasons. Actually.. here.. https://github.com/Debian/apt/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=YnPrompt&type= That's probably what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I want and thank you for guiding me through the sources.

Comment: Any idea on how to achieve this in `dnf`/`yum`, i.e. make prompts default to `[Y/n]` instead of `[y/N]`?